# Calculating variation of one variable within one experiment

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, experiment-design

I am conducting a preliminary study, where people assess (7-point likert scala) different pictures. Besides asking for my 2 Independent variables (which are the manipulations for my main study, an experiment) I included a third question, the covariate variable.

I need to calculate / quantify if this covariate variable changes for the several pictures or if the scores are similar.

All the analysis of variance (ANOVA, MANOVA, etc) I find compare always 2 or more different variables. In my case I don't want to compare Independent and Dependent variables. I just need to see if the rankings for the same variable differ significantly for the different pictures.

Are descriptive statistics (variance and SD) enough to statistically support the variation of the variable?

Thanks!